# How to position a div in the center at a specific height

Tags: html, css

I have a div which contains images that are sliding automatically vertically .Now as per my requirement i need to position this div to the center of the screen at a height of `78px` from top but i am not able to do it.
Here is my HTML..

```
<div id="slideshow-carousel">               
        <ul id="carousel" class="jcarousel jcarousel-skin-tango">
            <li><a href="#" rel="p1"><img src="images/1.jpg" width="960" height="583" alt="#"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="p2"><img src="images/2.jpg" width="960" height="583" alt="#"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="p3"><img src="images/3.jpg" width="960" height="583" alt="#"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="p4"><img src="images/4.gif" width="960" height="583" alt="#"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="p5"><img src="images/5.gif" width="960" height="583" alt="#"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="p6"><img src="images/6.gif" width="960" height="583" alt="#"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="p7"><img src="images/7.gif" width="960" height="583" alt="#"/></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS that i tried to add..

```
 <div id="slideshow-carousel" style="position:absolute;margin-top: 78px;align:center">
```

CSS..

```
        #slideshow-carousel {
            float:left; 
            width:960px;
            position:relative
        }

        #slideshow-carousel ul {
            margin:0; 
            padding:0;
            list-style:none;
        }

        #slideshow-carousel li {
            background:#fff; 
            height:583px; 
            position:relative
        }

        #slideshow-carousel li .arrow {
            left:3px; 
            top:28px; 
            position:absolute; 
            width:20px; 
            height:40px; 
            background:url(images/arrow_white.png) no-repeat 0 0; 
            display:block;
        }

        #slideshow-carousel li a {
            background:#000; 
            display:block; 
            width:960px; 
            height:583px;
        }
```

Please help me ..

Comment: where is your css? have you tried setting `position:absolute` and `top:78` OR `margin-top:78` ?

Comment: @Banana I have tried this as CSS style="position:absolute;margin-top: 78px;align:center" but div is not coming in center ..although it is coming 78 px down correct

Comment: show your css, so that we can easily identify the problem.

Comment: @user3664608 give your parent element `width:100%; text-align:center;`, and the carousel `margin:78 auto;`

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai I have added my CSS..

Comment: @Banana Please see my updated post for the CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a css class, and apply it to your div. Set the margins as you want, or keep it at auto.

```
.center
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:70%; 
    background-color:#b0e0e6;
}
```

Comment: Well you might as well use `margin: 78px auto 0;` to simplify.

Answer (score 0):

Have a fiddle - [Fiddle Link!](http://jsfiddle.net/h4sJj/)

HTML

```
<div id="slideshow-carousel">   
<!-- content -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
#slideshow-carousel { 
    margin: 78px auto 0; 
    width: 800px; 
    background: #CCC; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your #slideshow-carousel css like below.

```
#slideshow-carousel {
        margin:78px auto 0px;
        width:960px;
        position:relative
    }
```